# How to mock a list of CompletableFutures with exception using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

In my class, I have a private field `responseFutures`, that hold a list of CompletableFutures

```
public class ChunkRequests {
            ...
        
            private List<CompletableFuture<EvaluationResponse>> responseFutures =
                    new ImmutableList.Builder<>().addAll(responseFutures).build();  
            
    
            void setResponseFutures(List<CompletableFuture<EvaluationResponse>> responseFutures) {
                this.responseFutures = responseFutures;
            }
}
```

In the test, I want to be able to mock that `responseFutures` field, and when calling responseFutures.get(anyInt()), it should return a CompletableFuture containing an exception

Here is my implementation:

```
@Mock
ImmutableList<CompletableFuture<EvaluationResponse>> mockResponseFutures;

@Test
void test() {
        final ChunkRequests chunkRequests = new ChunkRequests();
        CompletableFuture<EvaluationResponse> exceptionFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        exceptionFuture.completeExceptionally(new InterruptedException());

        when(mockResponseFutures.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(exceptionFuture);
        chunkRequests.setResponseFutures(mockResponseFutures);
}
```

However, when I run the test, it complains about Unnecessary Stubbing on the line of

```
when(mockResponseFutures.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(exceptionFuture);
```

Any help would be appreciated, maybe it is not the root cause? Is it possible the `responseFutures` is not accessed in the test code after all?
Thanks!

Comment: There's never a reason to mock a `List`: you should just make a real one!  In this case, you can just make `Collections.nCopies(size, exceptionFuture)`.

Comment: But that's not the problem here. The problem is that you never call `get` on your list.

Comment: Also `private List<CompletableFuture<EvaluationResponse>> responseFutures = new ImmutableList.Builder<>().addAll(responseFutures).build();` doesn't compile.